# install libxml2 without internet connection so that nokigiri can be installed

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm

I am trying to install libxml2 on a redhat box which cannot connect to the internet.

So i downloaded and scped the following rpms:

```
libxml2-2.7.6-1.x86_64.rpm
libxml2-devel-2.7.6-1.x86_64.rpm
libxml2-python-2.7.6-1.x86_64.rpm
```

But I cannot install any of them:

```
-bash-4.1$ sudo rpm -Uvh libxml2-2.7.6-1.x86_64.rpm
warning: libxml2-2.7.6-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID de95bc1f: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libxml2 = 2.7.6-17.el6_6.1 is needed by (installed) libxml2-python-2.7.6-17.el6_6.1.x86_64
```

Is there a way i can install libxml2 with all the dependencies?

ideally i would like this version:

```
libxml2-2.7.6-1.X
```

Comment: It needs `2.7.6-17`...why do you want `2.7.6-1` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have another system with the same (or very similar) OS version on which it is installed (install it if necessary and possible) you can find out all its dependencies:

```
$ rpm -qR libxml2-2-2.9.1-7.2.1.x86_64
/sbin/ldconfig
/sbin/ldconfig
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit)
libdl.so.2()(64bit)
libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
libm.so.6()(64bit)
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libz.so.1()(64bit)
libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.2.3)(64bit)
libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.3.3)(64bit)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1
```

Then download and install the respective rpms as well.

May need a few iterations if some of the dependencies are themselves not satisfied.